# 1 Table with 1 Billion Rows vs. 1000 Tables with 1 Million Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I want to setup a schema for storing a large amount of sequential data up to billions of rows and once the data is inserted I'm only going to be reading it in future queries. I have two options for setting up my schema and wondering which one is better than the other below or if there is another option I'm not thinking of.

**Option 1.** 
Create a massive table to hold billions of rows of data. I like this because it keeps the schema static and life simple but not sure of any performance trade offs.

**Option 2.** 
 
In this instance I'm storing historical market data for stocks and the second option would be creating a table for each stock to spread the large volume of data across multiple tables in the db system. This feels like it would be more permanent but the down-side is having a mess if I want to add new columns to my data set in the future.

Looking for some warehouse lovers that can help me write this right the first time! - Duncan

Comment: I would consider one table that is partitioned if it were me.

Comment: You use partitioning with historical archive tables. If you're using data since 1980 for example, you could have a table for each year, partitioned by month.

Comment: I agree with HLGEM, one table partitioned.  There are special considerations when dealing with Very Large Databases (VLDBs).  Do some research and prepare yourself.  Here is one article: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9453.very-large-databases-vldbs.aspx

Comment: Partitioning is not about performance, it's a management feature. If you want to speed up queries, index properly.

Comment: Also try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table, but partitioned for easier maintenance. As far as the performance is concerned, create the appropriate indexes, don't rely on partitioning to improve performance (could be achieved in some cases, but not that simple as it seems).

Comment: Thanks, from you answers and the comments a partitioned table is route I want to go.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you would want to create [Partitioned Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with the data broken into smaller tables by date.  This will end up being much better for performance.  This will also be helpful with setting up tables on different Filegroups, which you will find is helpful for a backup strategy for that much data.